# Recording remote xserver output without x-forwarding

Tags: unix, linux, x11, x11forwarding

Any ideas for essentially creating a loop-back display on a remote server, so I run a X application, and instead of forwarding that display to a local client, the output is essentially 'screen-grabbed', just without a screen?

Explanation: High performance visualizations (read:pretty pretty pictures) with no interactivity needed while I'm 3000 miles away.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach you might use:

X Virtual frame buffer: http://www.x.org/archive/X11R6.8.1/doc/Xvfb.1.html

```
As an example, the following sequence of commands runs the virtual framebuffer
as display ":1", run a program on it, and capture the virtual screen in
the file image.xwd:

Xvfb :1 &
xv -display :1 &
xwd -display :1 -root -out image.xwd
```

Examplecommands from wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb

ImageMagik is capable of most things:

```
convert screen.xwd foo.png
```